# How to add custom font in bada

Tags: bada

Is it possible to set custom fonts in label text, button text, edit text. If possible then how that can be done. Anyone know please help me to solve this out

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the [Font](http://dpimg.ospos.net/contents/docs/apis/bada-V1.0.0b1/classOsp_1_1Graphics_1_1Font.html) class. Here you can find a tutorial: [BadaDev](http://www.badadev.com/the-better-labels-enrichedtext-in-bada/).